# "Parameter is invalid" when saving Bitmap to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, memorystream

I have an array of bitmaps which need compiling into a single, multi-page tiff image, however when saving the bitmap to a MemoryStream object I get the "Parameter is invalid" error message with no other detail.

The problem code:

```
private static MemoryStream convertToStream(Bitmap b)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
        return ms;
    }
}
```

The bitmaps are in 600x600 DPI with an average of 35 pages (equating to 35 bitmaps)

What I have tried:
I have confirmed the bitmap array contains the expected contents by saving them to disk

Any help is appreciated.

Stack trace:
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
at System.Drawing.Image.Save(Stream stream, ImageFormat format)
at ConfigureTiffDPI.Program.convertToStream(Bitmap b) in C:\Users<user>\source\repos\ConfigureTiffDPI\ConfigureTiffDPI\Program.cs:line 37
at ConfigureTiffDPI.Program.CompileBitmaps(Bitmap[] bitmaps) in C:\Users<user>\source\repos\ConfigureTiffDPI\ConfigureTiffDPI\Program.cs:line 44
at ConfigureTiffDPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users<user>\source\repos\ConfigureTiffDPI\ConfigureTiffDPI\Program.cs:line 29

[EDIT]
Given the comments I have edited the code as such:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

b.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Tiff);
return ms;
```

However the error still persists

Comment: You are returning the stream you created in a using clause. Sounds like a problem..

Comment: The code fails at the save line, it never reaches the return

Comment: Your code runs fine here with both jpg and a simple tif file.

Comment: If you return a MemoryStream object, you have to declare it without an `using` statement, otherwise you return a disposed object. If you have an exception before you return the stream, you have to specify the precise Format of the Bitmap(s) you're passing to the method, it may not be directly convertible (unless you're passing an already disposed Bitmap, as you're doing with the MemoryStream)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know why calling Save(stream) fails without knowing what the bitmap object contains exactly. But in general, to save multi-page TIFF, you need to call `System.Drawing.Image.Save()` once, followed by repeated calls to `SaveAdd`. The approach is the same whether you're saving to disk file or to memory stream.

There's a code sample from Microsoft on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.saveflag?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) that saves 3 pages to a TIFF file on disk. I changed the first parameter of `multi.Save()` from "Multiframe.tiff" to `ms`, which is the MemoryStream, and the code produced a valid multi-page TIFF in the stream. Here's the modified code:

```
Bitmap multi;
Bitmap page2;
Bitmap page3;
ImageCodecInfo myImageCodecInfo = null;
Encoder myEncoder;
EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter;
EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters;
// Create three Bitmap objects. imageFiles is a list of strings holding file names
multi = new Bitmap(imageFiles[0]);
page2 = new Bitmap(imageFiles[1]);
page3 = new Bitmap(imageFiles[2]);
int j;
ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
    if (encoders[j].MimeType == "image/tiff"/*mimeType*/)
    {
        myImageCodecInfo = encoders[j];
        break;
    }
myEncoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
multi.Save(ms, myImageCodecInfo, myEncoderParameters);
// Save the second page (frame).
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
multi.SaveAdd(page2, myEncoderParameters);
// Save the third page (frame).
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
multi.SaveAdd(page3, myEncoderParameters);
// Close the multiple-frame file.
myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
multi.SaveAdd(myEncoderParameters);
```

Another option to save multi-page TIFF to a stream is to use a professional imaging SDK like LEADTOOLS. (Disclosure: I work for its vendor). The code to load a list of images and save them into a TIFF stream is simply this:

```
using (RasterCodecs codecs = new RasterCodecs())
foreach (string imageFile in imageFiles) // list of strings holding file names
{
    RasterImage imagePage = codecs.Load(imageFile);
    ms.Position = 0; //rewind the memory stream to the start
    codecs.Save(imagePage, ms, RasterImageFormat.TifLzw, 24, 1, 1, -1, CodecsSavePageMode.Append);
}
```

Another advantage of using this SDK is the flexibility and added features. For example, to change the compression used for any page in the TIFF, replace `RasterImageFormat.TifLzw` with a different other value such as `RasterImageFormat.TifJpeg411` or `RasterImageFormat.CcittGroup4` to save using JPEG or FaxG4 compression, respectively. If you would like to try LEADTOOLS, There's a free evaluation [here](https://leadtools.com/downloads).